# Extract a date from a filename for CSH script?

Tags: scripts, csh

I am trying to write a CSH script that will look at components of the filename to generate a date/time. The problem is, I have no idea how to extract part of a filename to use it. Here is a sample filename:

```
nam_218_20140126_1800_001.grb
```

`20140126` is the date portion of the filename and `1800` is the time. I need to extract it and convert it to `2014-01-26_18:00:00` for use in an environment variable. Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% set filename='nam_218_20140126_1800_001.grb' 
% set datetime=`echo "$filename" | sed -r 's/.*_([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*/\1-\2-\3_\4:\5:00/'`
% echo $datetime
2014-01-26_18:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` and `cut`. Read `man cut`, and do something like:

```
$ csh
aardvark:~% set zz="nam_218_20140126_1800_001.grb"
aardvark:~% set y=`echo $zz|cut -c9-12`
aardvark:~% echo $y
2014
aardvark:~% set m=`echo $zz| cut -c13-14`
aardvark:~% echo $m
01
aardvark:~% set d=`echo $zz| cut -c15-16`
aardvark:~% echo $d
26
aardvark:~% set H=`echo $zz | cut -c18-19`
aardvark:~% echo $H
18
aardvark:~% set M=`echo $zz | cut -c20-21`
aardvark:~% echo $M
00
aardvark:~% echo "$y-$m-${d}_${H}:${M}:00"
2014-01-26_18:00:00
```

Not a `csh`-specific answer.